# How to run SQL query from Excel sheet and Import Output into the same sheet using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, python-2.7

I'm new to python I was trying to find solution for extracting the output of the sql query and importing it into the excel which has SQL query already.

For example I have two requirements

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1B7GN.png)
The above requirement has count query hence it was imported right next to it but if a query is like "select * from dbo" then the output i.e the entire table will be imported into sheet2 while it renames sheet2 as dbo